# In RDLC design, (how) can relative control alignments actually be set?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer

In the report designer, controls have a "Layout" context menu.  All the z-order options are available, but there are also relative alignment options (e.g "Align Center") that are always grayed out.

Is there a way to actually use relative alignments for report controls (say, to center a title, or an image)?  I'm not even seeing properties for that in the RDL spec itself...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - You can't, there are no container-alignment properties.  But you *can* adjust at design time if you dig into the menus enough.

The default Layout options are apparently meant to be used only relative to other controls, not containers.  So you can select one control, ctrl-select a second (at which point the layout options become enabled), and then use "align center", which will center the second wrt. the first.

Note that these options are not persistent properties, just at-that-moment adjustments - you would have to manually do so again any time you changed the relevant control positions/sizes.

You *can* auto-adjust similarly for form/report position, though *you can't do it with the default options on the Layout toolbar (or context menu)*.  Instead, you need to use the options under "Format->Center in Form" (and you only get centering there, obviously, not edge-alignment).  I customized my Layout toolbar to add the "Horizontally" option and now at least I can get on with my day.